# Need to change password

Tags: mac, google-chrome

My password needs to be changed on a website that I frequently purchase from. The old password is saved and the pop up box goes away too fast in Google Chrome. How can I fix this? (I am working on a Mac).

Comment: @Nifle I edited this. I hope it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In the upper left corner of your screen there is a small "box" that looks like three books set on their sides (if you hover over it it says "Customize and control Google Chrome"). Click on that. There will be an option called "settings" click on that.

Once you are in settings, scroll down to the bottom of the page; click on "Advanced settings". Scroll down to "Passwords and forms" there will be two check boxes here. One says "Enable Autofill..." the other is "Offer to save your web passwords". Click on the link beside the second one (which says "Manage Passwords"). Once you are here you may click the "x" to the right of the name of the website. Once you have done this, you can revisit the site, make the new user name or password and Chrome will ask if you want to save it. If you need additional help, visit [this Google help site](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?p=settings_password&rd=1).